# How to validate an Image

Tags: javascript, validation

I have `asp:FileUpload` field.

I want to be sure it's an image, validate it with validators

file FileUpload

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="P1Image" runat="server" />
```

file Validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="P1Image" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Choose an image"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I can send it to JS function but what is the test I need to do?

Comment: Can you check the file name extention? Or are you refering to further checks to see if it is a well formed image?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not a valid validation. People can bypass it with ease.

Use the asp control.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ValidationExpression="(.+\.([jJ][Pp][Gg])|.+\.([Pp][Nn][Gg])|.+\.([Gg][Ii][Ff]))"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Of course, this outputs JavaScript... but obviously you should have backend validation in addition to front-end validation.